# faster Fixnum multiplication in ruby?

Tags: ruby, performance, multiplication

using ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

I've been doing a lot of profiling and it's come to my attention that ruby Fixnum multiplication is really slow.

Through some profiling, I've learned that this is (partially) because **every call to Fixnum#* involves 6 calls to Kernel#kind_of**.

I know you can write C extensions, but these multiplications are spread throughout the code.  So, is there anyway to avoid this overhead inside Ruby?

thanks

Comment: That's pretty interesting. What are you using to profile the code? I would have guessed the native Ruby multiplication was relatively efficient.

Comment: @BlakeTaylor I'm using ruby-prof

Answer (score 5):

I seriously doubt that those measurements are accurate, for several reasons:

1. You don't state which implementation of Ruby you are using, but `ruby-prof` is a Ruby profiler. It profiles Ruby code. There is no Ruby implementation I know of where `Fixnum#*` is Ruby code. In MRI, YARV, MRuby and tinyrb it is C code, in Rubinius it is C++ code, in MacRuby it is Objective-C code, in JRuby and XRuby it is Java code, in RubyGoLightly it is Go code, in IronRuby and Ruby.NET it is C# code, in MagLev and SmallRuby it is Smalltalk code, in Cardinal it is PASM code. `ruby-prof` can profile Ruby code, it cannot profile C, C++, Objective-C, Java, C#, Go, Smalltalk or PASM. Only Ruby. Therefore, it simply *cannot* profile `Fixnum#*`.
2. There is no need for `Fixnum#*` to check the class more than once. It knows that `self` is a `Fixnum`, because otherwise the call wouldn't have dispatched to the `Fixnum#*` method in the first place, so it only needs to check the argument. It also needs to check whether the result will fit into a `Fixnum` or not, but it would do that internally, not by a call to `kind_of?` (in fact, that doesn't even make sense: in order to be able to call a method on the result of the multiplication, it would first have to construct the result object, and in order to construct the result object, it would already have to know whether it fits into a `Fixnum` or not).
3. It wouldn't do that class check by calling `kind_of?` and going through the entire Ruby method lookup and method dispatch machinery. It's an internal function of the Ruby implementation, it has access to all private internal implementation details, it would just check the class directly or call some internal interpreter function, not the Ruby method `kind_of?`
4. I checked the implementation of `Fixnum#*` in various popular Ruby implementations and didn't find *any* calls to `kind_of?`. Unfortunately, you didn't state which Ruby implementation you are using.

   - Rubinius: [`Fixnum::mul` in `vm/builtin/fixnum.cpp` l. 78–89](https://GitHub.Com/Rubinius/Rubinius/blob/master/vm/builtin/fixnum.cpp#L78-89)
   - YARV: [`fix_mul` in `numeric.c` l. 2596–2640](https://GitHub.Com/Ruby/Ruby/blob/trunk/numeric.c#L2596-2640)
   - JRuby: [`org.jruby.RubyFixnum.{op_mul, multiplyFixnum, multiplyOther}` in `src/org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java` l. 472–520](https://GitHub.Com/JRuby/JRuby/blob/master/src/org/jruby/RubyFixnum.java#L472-520) (Here you can clearly see, for example, how the method uses the Java `instanceof` operator instead of Ruby's `kind_of?` method to check the class.)

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I could certainly be wrong about this. Here's what I'm seeing my profiler output:  


     `23.52%   9.49%      5.17      2.08      0.00      3.08           808533      Fixnum#*`  
                        `2.27      2.27      0.00      0.00  4851198/5355534      Kernel#kind_of?`  

I'm not sure if you're familiar with ruby-prof graph output, but the lines underneath a method name are methods called from that method.  
I have no idea what implementation I'm using.  It either came with Ubuntu or I got it from apt-get.  Do you know how I can find out?

Comment: You were right, BTW.  See my answer if you're curious about what was happening.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think I figured it out.  I'm using the GSL libray, and it appears that it patches Fixnum#* with code you can see here: https://github.com/romanbsd/rb-gsl/blob/master/lib/gsl/oper.rb#L15

This code includes... wait for it... 6 calls to Kernel#kind_of? in a big ol' 'or' statement.

I'm not going to pretend to totally understand how it works or why it happens, but the code path matches perfectly with the profiler output.